# Weird C Behaviour with fopen and testing for NULL

Tags: c, if-statement, fopen

I have the following code to open a input and output file:

```
if ((source_file_ptr = fopen(source_filename, "rb")) == NULL) {
  error("unable to open input file");
}
if ((output_file_ptr = fopen(output_filename, "wb")) == NULL) {
  error("unable to open output file");
}
```

This is goood simple way to catch errors in opening the files.

However after some editing overall to my program, the program now crashes instead of catching an invalid output file.

I tried a several things without success but interestingly when I try this:

```
if ((output_file_ptr = fopen(output_filename, "wb")) == NULL) printf("fail");
exit(0);
if ((source_file_ptr = fopen(source_filename, "rb")) == NULL) {
  error("unable to open input file");
}
if ((output_file_ptr = fopen(output_filename, "wb")) == NULL) {
  error("unable to open output file");
}
```

It will print "fail" (and obviously exit without much more insight).

But if I comment out the exit(0) line, it will again exhibit the same crash behaviour without printing "fail" nor catching the error.

I can't explain why this is... I suspected a dangling pointer but the only preceding lines of code within the function are already enclosed in if-else if-else all with braces. There are only a few other functions delcared above but I've checked and ensured they're all enclosed in braces.

I'm still learning C, any thoughts on what's going on here?
Thanks as a lot!

Note: enclosing printf("fail") with braces doesn't alter the behaviour I observe.

EDIT: additional code that follows the above:

```
if (fread(&file_struct, sizeof(file_struct), 1, source_file_ptr) < 1) {
   error("unable to read %s", source_filename);
}
else {
   error_check(file_struct);

  if (fwrite(&file_struct, sizeof(file_struct), 1, output_file_ptr) < 1) {
     error("unable to write file header");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post subsequent code after these `if`s? These `if`s will print messages if a failure is encountered but the file pointers may still be used.

Comment: Use `perror()` for a description of the error.

Comment: You might need some {} around the printf() and the exit().

Comment: Try printing a newline to flush the output buffer. I suspect you get the error but don't see it because it's "hidden": `printf("fail\n");`

Comment: @hmjd added additional code - thxs

Comment: Does that new code unconditionally follow the `if`s ?

Comment: @wildplasser adding braces doesn't change the outcome. In anycase they were added as part of working out why the first piece of code was no longer working.

Comment: @hmjd that's the code that exactly follows the problematic if statements

Comment: if it crashes: use a debugger to let it tell you where it crashes, stop fiddling around with printf-debugging.

Comment: Ok. Added a short `gdb` introduction to comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd check is that `source_filename` was a valid C string. I'd then check `output_filename` in the same way.

If it turns out your changes have somehow corrupted either or both of them, you're into undefined territory behaviour.

The use of a debugger would be ideal here since you could set a breakpoint at the start of that code then single-step through, checking variables that you're about to use.

The other thing you should check is whether your calls to `error` actually return (rather than, for example, call `exit`).

If they do then, even though the `fopen` calls returned NULL, you're still going to pass that to `fread` and/or `fwrite`,  a definite no-no.

Since your second case prints `"fail"`, it's a given that you have some problem opening the output file. Using the NULL handle from that would not be a good thing.

If that function *does* return, then you should be using something like:

```
if ((source_file_ptr = fopen(source_filename, "rb")) == NULL) {
  error("unable to open input file");
  return;
}
if ((output_file_ptr = fopen(output_filename, "wb")) == NULL) {
  fclose (source_file_ptr);
  error("unable to open output file");
  return;
}
```

Comment: I can verify that I haven't set output_filename (pointer) to point to anything and output_filename==NULL returns false. If I don't provide source_filename it will return the error message. It just won't do it for output. Even if I switch the order of the if statements.

Comment: Apologies I should add that error prints the message and also exits with exit(-1)

Comment: @xlm, then you need to either _print_ the values to confirm their content, including flushing afterwards to ensure you don't lost it due to a core dump) or run it through a debugger. Seriously, if possible, do the latter. It should tell you _exactly_ what the problem is rather than us trying to guess (however intelligent those guesses may be).

Answer (score 2):

The "fail" will not, necessarily, show if you have buffered output - as it crash, and do not exit and hence flush output buffers.

If you do

> setbuf(stdout, NULL);

I'll guess you'll get the `fail` printed, also without the `exit`.

As mentioned by @caf below, also check if `fflush()` is better suited:

[stdio.h](http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html#stdio.h)

---

**Edit:**
This might be a bit clutter, but, since you confirmed linux + gcc I'll add it, a very short gdb intro, and in ??% the best way to attack:

1. Add `-ggdb`to your compile line [3.9 Options for Debugging Your Program or GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options).
2. Start a gdb session:

   - If you use arguments: `$ gdb -args my_prog arg1 arg2`
   - Else: `$ gdb my_prog`
   - *Arguments can also be provided inside gdb*
3. Set breakpoint:

   - `(gdb) break 112` , <- where 112 is linenumber, or
   - `(gdb) break main`, <- where main is function
   - `(gdb) break foo.c:bar`, <- where `foo.c` is file and `bar` is function
   - *And quite a few other ways*
4. Start execution: `(gdb) run`
5. When program encounters break point it stops, from here you can i.e.:

   - `(gdb) print output_filename`, <- print value of filename
   - `(gdb) print *source_file_ptr`, <- print what this points to
   - `(gdb) list`, list -, list linenumber, etc <- print source
   - *and a vast list of other things*
6. To continue you can do i.e.:

   - `(gdb) next`, <- step proceeding trough subroutine calls.
   - `(gdb) step`, <- step until different source line, (I.e. in to a function)
   - `(gdb) continue`, <- Continue execuition, til next breakpoint, end of program or other.
   - *And so forth*
7. To quit: `(gdb) quit`

Most frequently used gdb instructions has a one letter abbreviation. I.e. `r` for `run`, `b` for `break`, `n` for `next` etc. It also has tab completion for known variables.

A lot of commands also takes a numeric, or other, argument. I.e. `next 8`

Use manual, man pages etc. and while running you can also issue help commands. I.e. `(gdb) help run`

Comment: Rather than removing buffering entirely, you can simply add a call to `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` call to flush the buffers.

Comment: @caf Indeed. Thought of it, but considered that in a debug situation it's simpler to turn it off, as in, i.e., if one have multiple test printf's. But I should have mentioned it. Lazy me.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the short intro to the gdb! Just downloaded; was looking for a intro

Comment: @xlm: It is actually easy to get started with, and has a very long list of features. In my opinion a great tool both for beginner and expert. You should also check `valgrind` if you have not. I.e. `$ valgrind ./my_prog` often gives you what you need very quickly. It also warns you about other bad things and list if you have any memory leakage. - On occasion I also use `ddd` with gdb.